# Exporting from html table to excel

Tags: javascript, html

It works good but the excel file is without gridlines. Can someone help me? Thanks.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
        var dt = new Date();
        var day = dt.getDate();
        var month = dt.getMonth() + 1;
        var year = dt.getFullYear();
        var postfix = day + "." + month + "." + year;
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
        var table_div = document.getElementById('dvData');
        var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
        a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
        a.download = 'sold_' + postfix + '.xls';
        a.click();
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you update your fiddle so we can see the result?

Comment: it works, i just added border to my table. <table border="1px"> and it export with grids. Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to wrap the table with `html` document. Also, you need to convert the output to base64.

Here is article and working demo that explain how to export html table to excel table with styles.

Check this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/755203/Export-HTML-table-to-Excel-With-CSS